# Android: call a method that belongs to AsyncTask class

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a `class` B and there I want to call a method `getSomething(type, option)`, which belongs to `class` A which extends `AsyncTask` and is inside `class` C.

My `class` C is:

```
public class C extends BaseActivity{
(...)
 public class A extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
 (...)
  public String doInBackground(String... params) {
  (...)
  }
  public String getSomething(String type, String option){
  (...)
  }
  protected void onPreExecute() {
  (...)
  }
  protected void onPostExecute(String result){
  (...)
  }
(...)
}
```

I'm trying to call in class B, the method `getSomething(...)`:

```
public class B{
(...)
public void methodInClassB(String type, String option){

    String sentence = new C().new A().getSomething(type,option);
}
```

I've also tried unsuccessfully this:

```
new C().new A().execute(type,option);
```

I can't call `getSomething()` method because I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
```

every time it is called in `class` B.

Does anyone can help me? How can I call from class B the method getSomething(...)?

Answer (score 0):

question seems unclear 
try this

- inside class B keep a method to call the Async task - methodInClassB
- create an object of class B in your Currant class
- call class B using your object ,and call  methodInClassB

Comment: I had edited the post for you understand how I have class B made. Inside class B I have a method and inside that method I want to call the getSomething() from the AsyncTask().